# How can I show data using a modal when clicking a table row using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
<h1>Orders</h1>

<table class="table table-striped" <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Customer</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-toggle="modal" data-id="1" data-target="#orderModal">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>24234234</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-toggle="modal" data-id="2" data-target="#orderModal">
            <td>2</td>
            <td>24234234</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-toggle="modal" data-id="3" data-target="#orderModal">
            <td>3</td>
            <td>24234234</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div id="orderModal" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="orderModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">x</button>
         <h3>Order</h3>

    </div>
    <div id="orderDetails" class="modal-body"></div>
    <div id="orderItems" class="modal-body"></div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#orderModal').modal({
        keyboard: true,
        backdrop: "static",
        show:false,
        
    }).on('show', function(){
          var getIdFromRow = $(event.target).closest('tr').data('id');
        //make your ajax call populate items or what even you need
        $(this).find('#orderDetails').html($('<b> Order Id selected: ' + getIdFromRow  + '</b>'))
    });
});
<script>
```

I have tried this but not working in codeigniter.

Comment: Please include the expected behaviour and the problem you are facing. You can [edit] your question to include snippets so that we can run it and help you better.

Answer (score 0):

**Working Demo:** https://dojo.telerik.com/aSEkagaW/6

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("click", "table tbody tr", function(e) {
        var getIdFromRow = $(e.currentTarget).data("id");
        $('#orderDetails').html($('<b> Order Id selected: ' + getIdFromRow + '</b>'))
    })

    $('#orderModal').modal({
        keyboard: true,
        backdrop: "static",
        show: false,
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<h1>Orders</h1>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-toggle="modal" data-id="1" data-target="#orderModal">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>24234234</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-toggle="modal" data-id="2" data-target="#orderModal">
            <td>2</td>
            <td>24234234</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-toggle="modal" data-id="3" data-target="#orderModal">
            <td>3</td>
            <td>24234234</td>
            <td>A</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div id="orderModal" class="modal hide fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="orderModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Order</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div id="orderDetails" class="modal-body"></div>
            <div id="orderItems" class="modal-body"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing information.Code is now working properly.